# prove using strong mathematical induction $S_{k}=2^{((k+1)/2)}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I used induction to find the following formula:
$S_{k}=2^{((k+1)/2)}$ for when k is odd. I now need to use induction to prove this formula is right.

I'm not sure how to prove this using strong mathematical induction. Any help is appreciated. I know you are meant to plug (k+2) in for k is that the only difference?

edit - $S_{k}=2S_{k-2}$

Comment: What is $S_k? $

Comment: What is $S_k\,$?

Comment: What is $S_k$ ?

Comment: Can't believe no one asked! Pardon me but what is $S_k$?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I have edited in what $S_{k}$ is. I aplogize. Not used to this type of problem.

Comment: What is $S_k$?  Also, a lack of familiarity with a problem type doesnt explain why you wouldnt ask a complete question. The need for complete questions doesnt change with the problem. My 2cents.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I added $S_{k}$ into my question. I think the problem is now complete I aplogize for that. Please check my edit. Thank you!

Comment: I was teasing you. :P Do you not know what strong induction is?  If you can answer a problem with "weak induction"... or rather just "induction"... which is easier in this case... I dont know why you'd have to use strong induction.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I'm practicing Strong induction for a quiz in my discrete mathematics class. I'm trying to see how to complete this problem so I can further my understanding. I am clueless on strong mathematical induction. But am proficient i'd say at normal induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $S_1=2$. Base case is obvious (k=1,2). Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and suppose $S_k=2^{(k+1)/2}$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$. Now, it follows that $$S_{n+1}=2S_{n-1}=2(2^{(n)/2})=2^{1+(n)/2}=2^{(n+2)/2}.$$ Hence by PMI, $S_k=2^{(k+1)/2}$ is true for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.         $_\square$

Remarks: Strong induction is just like induction, except you are assuming that $k$ is true for all $1\leq k\leq n$ instead of just $n$.

Comment: Im no expert in strong induction myself but youre not even using all $n$ cases being true. Your proof here is precisely the same as a regular inductive argument.  You never utilized the truth of previous iterations.

Comment: Yeah, just had to use strong cause induction assumes only $n$, we need $n-1$. Anyways the two are equivalent